# Sublime Text 2 API ability to run nodejs script on editor start

Tags: python, api, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm developing [**plugin**](https://github.com/matmuchrapna/STsync) which will synchronize Sublime Text configuration.

The plugin core is node.js utility, which is doing all the stuff.

The next step I see is to create python wrapper for plugin which will interact  with [**Sublime Text API**](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html) and will **run nodejs scipt every time text editor is opening**.
And the main problem is that I don't know python.

I have researched that I need to execute this custom python code:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["node", "app.js", "../User/"], Shell=true)
```

Then I researched API and I thought that I need [**`EventListener` class**](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener), but there are no events like `onEditorStart`. Then I found two `run_command(string, <args>)`, but I have any thoughts how to use it in my purposes.

Then I have explored `Packages/Default/` with samples of code, which are using a lot of API functions, but still I have no idea how find usefull lines in that 101 files.

I am almost in despair, and decided to ask here. What should I code in python to force my plugin **run nodejs scipt every time text editor is opening?**

Comment: Would it be overkill if you run your plugin every time a a tab is created?

Comment: @CarlosV Yes, it will be overkill. And I have already found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[José F. Romaniello](https://twitter.com/jfroma) suggested working [solution](https://gist.github.com/4597188) at gist.github.com

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
from subprocess import call


class TestCommand(sublime_plugin.ApplicationCommand):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestCommand, self).__init__()
        #do your stuf here
        # call(["node", "app.js", "../User/"], Shell=true)
        call(["ping", "192.168.1.1"])

    def run(self, edit):
        pass
```